# imageWithContentsOfFile Not Returning Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

I have used this method a hundred times before and it used to always work, but now it just returns" Null", I googled and I tried with

```
            NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:
                                   @"fileName" ofType:@"png"];
            UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But its still not Working, 
Also tried using

UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

still get "Null",

And I can't use the Method

```
  UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Since I am downloading the Images inside my Apps Document Directory inside a "tmp" folder and then using the path where I have downloaded them and then trying to access it, Hence I need this method "imageWithContentsOfFile:" to work desperately

can somebody please help me out of this…Thanks for help in advance

Comment: try [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"];

Comment: Is image format supported? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html. Can you open it by other means?

Comment: imageNamed has caching implications that are different than imageWithContentsOfFile.  If it is a one use image(especially if large) then often imageWithContentsOfFile or its ilk are preferable.

Comment: Yes the Image is a .png file only

Comment: Just to mention: Apple states that resources that can be recreated (like images) must be stored inside the temp folder, not the documents folder.

Comment: You are right Lukas this is the an example of the path were I store the Images, I do store it inside a "tmp" Directory

 "/C9509A83-F143-4711-B2B7-1F7BF80B8B87/tmp/try-4.png"
And I just went and Checked on this path and Image is present here but not getting Loaded

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if the issue I was having is the same as yours but we were suddenly having this issue where we were getting nil for our images when using the full file path and using the imageWithContentsOfFilePath method.

We found after a bit of debugging that the NSHomeDirectory() (which is basically your sandbox location), now changes on every launch. Our issue was that we were storing the entire file path and on subsequent launches, trying to retrieve them from that same full file path, which no longer existed.

For example, on one launch your home directory might be: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/844B1DDA-49AB-4B5C-AC76-2BBF1397B142 but it would be different on the next: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C620B610-3839-4134-9DF7-C5756F22BBCE. Therefore, if you store file paths for future use, you'll have to determine the home directory portion of the file path at the time you require it and simply store the relative path of the file/image.

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self retrieveHomeDirectoryPath], relativeFileLocationPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Here retrieveHomeDirectoryPath would simply return the result of NSHomeDirectory() or NSTemporaryDirectory() and relativeFileLocationPath would be the path relative to that specific location.

Comment: Could you please share with us what retrieveHomeDirectoryPath does?

Comment: Having the same problem, the solution of RebeccaDuhard worked well for me. @rcat24 the method retrieveHomeDirectoryPath body should look like this "NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES); return [paths objectAtIndex: 0];" NSDocumentDirectory can be replaced by one of the NSSearchPathDirectory enums.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the info that the directory changes on launch. I was just banging my head against that for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is something wrong with your import. Xcode does funky things sometimes.

Right click on the image in your resources and delete and remove the reference. Reimport and make sure that you select the box that says copy.

This is how I set images.

```
self.someUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"somePictureThatExists.png"]];
```

Or more simply:

```
self.someUIImageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"somePictureThatExists.png"];
```

**Edit:**

I would also clean the project when you run into issues like this.

Command+Shift+K or `Product>Clean`

Comment: I think I should Have Specified that I am Downloading the Images and storing them in my App's Document directory, and then accessing them through the path in "filePath" where I have stored, Hence I need only this function to work "imageWithContentsOfFile"

Comment: @Geet Are you sure what I have above still doesnt work? As I understand UIImage class is an overloaded class which searches by image type in the coreSystem (your sandbox). I thought that would work. But Im not 100% sure since I've never done that.

Comment: It didn't work, I had to change my entire approach because of this, It would be still helpful if anyone gives a reason as to why this function stopped working

Answer (score 0):

As you have to load image from Documents Directory 1st access it using below code

```
NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 

    NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *pngfile = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.png"];

    & then apply filename to imageview like

     imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngfile]];
```

Here the filename.png is the name of png file which you have saved in Applications Document directory.

Comment: Its not Stored Inside a Documents Directory , the Images are stored Inside a Temporary Directory , right where the Documents folder is located in the directory path